# Python datetime to microtime

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

I've looked all around, and there seem to be a lot of hacks, but no simple, "good" ways to do this. I want to convert a Python `datetime` object into microtime like `time.time()` returns (seconds.microseconds).

What's the best way to do this? Using `mktime()` strips off the microseconds altogether, you could conceivably build up a `timedelta`, but that doesn't seem right. You could also use a `float(strftime("%s.%f"))` (accounting for rounding seconds properly), but that seems like a super-hack.

What's the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond / 1000000.0
```

works if you don't want to use `strftime` and `float`.

It returns the same thing as `time.time()` with `dt = datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: If the timezone for datetime object and your local timezone may not be the same, you should use calendar.gmtime(dt.utctimetuple()) instead

Comment: I think you mean `calendar.timegm`, and that gives the same answer as Mark's version -- meaning it's incorrect for non-UTC `datetime` objects. The time since the epoch for me is the same as for someone in UTC, not different by my UTC offset.

Comment: It's always correct regardless of your timezone, since dt.utctimetuple returns time tuple of the datetime object in UTC. And calendar.timegm takes a utc timetuple.

Comment: Did you try it? `time.time()` and `calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.now().utctimetuple())` don't give the same time since the epoch for non-UTC timezones, while the same amount of time has passed since the epoch no matter what time zone you're talking about, since the epoch was UTC and `time.time()` returns time in UTC.

Comment: I see. I'm using calendar.timegm on my website. It works perfectly because my datetime object carries tzinfo. And it seems the datetime object returned by datetime.datetime.now() doesn't contain tzinfo, thus utctimetuple doesn't return the correct result (in lack of tzinfo, utctimetuple returns the same result as timetuple)

Comment: So it sounds like your version works for timezone-aware objects or UTC, Mark's works for UTC, mine works for local timezone objects. If you post yours as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def microtime(dt):
    unixtime = dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
    return unixtime.days*24*60*60 + unixtime.seconds + unixtime.microseconds/1000000.0
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the same as `time.time()` for `datetime.datetime.now()`. Looks like you're assuming `dt` is UTC, so you'll be off by the timezone's UTC-offset.

Comment: @agf, what is `time.time()`? I can't find it in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Comment: Not `datetime.time`, `time.time()` -- http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time

Comment: @agf: so much for "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." I never knew about `time` before. And you're correct, my solution assumes you're passing a UTC datetime.

Comment: /agree, `datetime` / `time` / `calendar` is a mess.

Comment: I agree it is a mess.  I wrote my own functions to deal with it when I wrote PyFeed.  http://home.avvanta.com/~steveha/pyfeed.html

Answer (score -1):

import time;

microtime=int(time.time()*1000);

print microtime;

Comment: Why are there semicolons after your statements?