# Python get micro time from certain date

Tags: python, file, datetime, time

I was browsing the Python guide and some search machines for a few hours now, but I can't really find an answer to my question.

I am writing a switch where only certain files are chosen to be in the a file_list (list[]) when they are modified after a given date.

In my loop I do the following code to get its micro time:

```
file_time = os.path.getmtime(path + file_name)
```

This returns me a nice micro time, like this: 1342715246.0

Now I want to compare if that time is after a certain date-time I give up. So for testing purposes, I used 1790:01:01 00:00:00.

```
# Preset (outside the class/object)
start_time = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
start_time = start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# In my Method this check makes sure I only append files to the list
#   that are modified after the given date
if file_time > self.start_time:
    file_list.append(file_name)
```

Of course this does not work, haha :P. What I'm aiming for is to make a micro time format from a custom date. I can only find ClassMethods online that make micro time formats from the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Python datetime to microtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238226/python-datetime-to-microtime). You need the following snippet:

```
def microtime(dt):
    time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond / 1000000.0
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks :D. I've tested it on the files that were created yesterday after 21:00 (09:00 PM) and it works superb. Now the final step is that I will add a buffer List that will mirror each few seconds (LIVE) if new files are to be processed. This way I want to minimize the reprocessing of files that are already processed in a LIVE looping session. Again; thanks so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `datetime.datetime` objects by themselves. If you keep `start_time` as a `datetime.datetime` object and make `file_time` a `datetime.datetime` object, you can successfully do `file_time > self.start_time`

Take a look at the supported operators [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)